# How do I get/copy a password from kwallet

Tags: git, kde, kde-plasma-5

My experience with kwallet (for those of us running KDE) so far is it's the thing that pops up to receive passwords for git. At this point I promptly type my password in the username field because it looks like a password box and then it remembers it for good so I can't type the username in. This is great and all for when I don't want to type my password all the time for git commands, but what do I do if I want access to the password myself?

I can run `kwalletmanager5` and under `Contents -> ksshaskpass -> Passwords` I see the entry I want. Right click provides no "open" or "copy-password". "Show Contents" opens a text box with just the username. Where's the actual password?

Answer (score 2):

Copying the password entry in the left panel (either ctrl-c or right click "copy") will actually copy the password to the clipboard, not the URL shown.

Comment: Does right-clicking show the available commands & shortcuts? If so, KeePass sounds similar that way

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes. The right click menu just has "Copy" which at first I never tried because I assumed it would copy the text of the item, which is the URL/name for the password store.